# What motives would an omnipotent being have for ruining a universe it created?

Tags: gods, universe

## Background

In a fantasy world I am working on, the universe was created by an omnipotent (but not omnipresent or omniscient) entity known as the Storyteller. Inside this new universe the Storyteller places several gods to create and maintain a world of humanoid races. Each of the gods has a specific role, such as one who has the ability to create matter and is tasked with building the world, one who is gifted with unparalleled intelligence and is tasked with writing the laws of physics, or one who is able to generate light and is tasked with creating the sun/stars.

Over time, the Storyteller continues to add more gods with tasks and abilities that benefit the inhabitants of its universe. However, the Storyteller eventually has a change of heart and decides to create gods with negative tasks and abilities. The Storyteller's universe becomes plagued with evil gods, ones that destroy and cause chaos. Ultimately, the Storyteller decides to create a god-killer, one who has the ability to kill other gods with a single touch. This god-killer is tasked with destroying the original gods and succeeds, plunging the universe into a perpetual state of chaos and war.

## The Storyteller's Traits

- Being an omnipotent entity, the Storyteller can change anything in the universe it created
- Despite not being omniscient, the Storyteller's mind is capable of storing an unlimited amount of information. If it were to study every single individual in every single moment of time in its universe, it could essentially become omniscient by knowing everything that has ever happened and would happen. It has not attempted to do this.
- The Storyteller is outside of time, meaning that it can see any moment in the past, present, or future of its universe. Additionally, the Storyteller can insert a physical incarnation of itself into any place in its universe at any moment in time.
- The Storyteller has similar emotions to that of humans except that they are much more intense. When angered, the Storyteller will often immediately resort to violence; when joyous, the Storyteller will create another beneficial god or bless whoever has pleased it. Despite this, the Storyteller dislikes displaying its emotions and will step out of time whenever it thinks it will do something rash. It is not always able to predict its own emotional outbursts.
- The Storyteller has little inhibition against harming the inhabitants of its universe. When it created the first gods, they disobeyed it and did not complete the tasks they were given. In a fit of rage, the Storyteller killed several of the gods and then created an artifact that would psychically torment any gods that continued to disobey.

## The Question

Given this background, what motives would cause the Storyteller to turn against the universe it created by making the god-killer?

## My Current Ideas

Originally, I was thinking that the Storyteller's motivation would be that it created the universe simply for entertainment and became bored with the lack of conflict in its universe. However, I dislike this idea because I intend for the Storyteller to be a prominent character who semi-frequently interacts with its universe's inhabitants. The entertainment motive does not work well in this situation because the Storyteller would have to care for what it has created to some degree in order for it to speak to them directly.

Another option is that the Storyteller has some kind of hidden goal in ruining the universe. I'm not sure what the Storyteller would hope to gain from this though.

Comment: Isn't this the old [problem of evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil), the study of which has occupied philosophers and theologians for a very long time?

Comment: Questions about actions and motivations of an individual tend to be off-topic here in Wordlbuilding SE.

Comment: this is probably going to be flagged as off-topic

Comment: This question does not ask 'what the character should do'. It asks about the possible motivations of a creature who is a member of a defined class: Humans with the human range of emotions and psychological reactions. Psychology studies humans and their motivations. It is possible to answer this question from a theoretical point of view and offer a list of the most likely motivations for destructive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**Storyteller does not change.**

/The Storyteller is outside of time, meaning that it can see any moment in the past, present, or future of its universe. Additionally, the Storyteller can insert a physical incarnation of itself into any place in its universe at any moment in time./

It knows that in the future it adds god killers.  It knows that when it turns the lights on for the first time.  It knows there will be endless war.  A being outside of time does not change with the seasons.  It is in all the seasons at once; all the seasons that have ever been or will be.

What changes are the people inside of time.  From their perspective they perceive change in the structure of the game as time goes on and it does change.  Those changes were intended from the beginning because it was all known to the Storyteller from the beginning.

As regards why the Storyteller has set it up that way, others have wondered this too.  [There was a man in the land of Uz whose name was Job](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+1&version=KJV).  Job has some insights into these matters that are worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer needs to come from outside the Storyteller's toy universe (that is from the world the Storyteller came from). Figure out what is motivating all this effort and you've got your answer. The easy one is "An all-good universe is dull, little better than no universe at all."

And why is regularly interacting with the created universe a reason not to mess with it? Certainly the Abrahamic God had no compunction about doing so. Given the name "Storyteller" it could be the usual trope of a hero setting out on a quest, well all the pieces need to be placed in that hero's way. In that it' like setting up a bunch of dominoes only to watch them all fall over.

Answer (score 1):

### You needed worthy opponents.

The god has become absolutely obsessed with a particular race that really impressed it. The stories they tell, the way they act, the boldness of them. He noticed this particular race were most happy when facing challenges.

As such, the hostile gods were designed to elevate this race above others. He also gave this race lots of blessings and buffs so they could continue to do amazing despite the hostile gods.

Unfortunately, the other races didn't get all the top blessings and so are doing very poorly.

Answer (score 1):

### A few Thoughts:

The motives of an omnipotent being start to become really complex when you factor in a different set of values and goals. I'll look at a few of these.

- [**Sand Mandalas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand_mandala): Your god views the universe like a Buddhist sand mandala. The monks create immensely detailed mandalas portraying religious principles, and when they are done, they take a broom and sweep the whole thing up. It is symbolic of the temporary and insignificant nature of the material world. Your god has used immense effort to create a beautiful work of art - the universe. He may take a moment to appreciate it, but allowing himself to become attached to material desire is to give up omnipotence and make preservation of something outside himself more important. His love of the world is why he must destroy it.
- **[Time is a three-dimensional concept](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176601/is-three-dimensional-time-consistent-and-paradox-free-for-time-dimension-travele) to the god**: Your god views reality very differently than we do. The universe has a past, present, future, and parallel universes all existing in a greater reality. The idea of NOW is where the god is paying attention to at the moment. He can be anywhere in time at any instance of his existence, so if the universe is destroyed, that just means there is an end. He still can experience the universe after it is destroyed, since it exists in the past. After all, every story has an ending and can be reread.
- **Parallel universes**: There is still a universe in the multiverse where everything is perfect. But to make the universe greater (and bigger), he must have variations where things are different. So the god is creating additional universes where different events and outcomes happen. Being omnipotent but not omniscient, he hopes to find a universe where the final outcome is even more perfect than the perfect universe he created. But to do that, he has to try less likely scenarios to perfection. Or perhaps, as a storyteller, he wants every possible story to have a chance to unfold in some possible universe.

Answer (score 0):

**Fear of reprisal**

The Storyteller created benevolent, obedient gods.  These gods are  worshipped by humans.  When a god disobeys the Storyteller, they experience agony.  Humans begin to resent the Storyteller for that pain.  They begin to wonder whether the Storyteller is evil and should be destroyed for harming their beloved deities.  Left unchecked, they would find a way to rise up and destroy him.  So he does what he has to.  He gives them a more immediate threat:  each other.

Pitting those you would subjugate against each other to stay on top has been the elite's go to strategy as long as there's been one to take down.