# How could a time paradox caused by a manufactured deity fail to produce a full retcon of history?

Tags: time-travel, time, gods

The Leviathan https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Scarlet_King   is an entity formed as the manifestation of the tension between the modern world and the pre-modern world and the rage it creates. Originally it existing as the concept of there being something greater than man, such as gods or the supernatural, that could not be controlled or reasoned with. Modern ideas spurred on by the scientific revolution and the enlightenment encouraged humanity to understand their surrounding environment with a new perspective that focused on rationality and proven facts based on trial and error analysis. This concept of the Leviathan was then shaped by the encroachment of modernity into the old world and the clash between the two. An organization known as "The cult of the Leviathan" seeks to reincarnate their deity on the mortal plane directly in the form of a human child with Leviathan's soul. The group seek to return the world to its pre-modern age where humanity After being born into the world through mortal means, he will grow up to become the living manifestation of their god and subjugate humanity to his rule, with the cult at the helm of power. This plan would have severe consequences that are more far reaching than even the cult had planned.

Time works in a linear fashion, with the past, present, and future all occurring simultaneously. The laws that govern the universe (gravity, physics, etc.) work in tandem to create our reality and what counts for normalcy, acting as stabilizers to keep it together. However, reality is fragile, and can be disrupted by an outside force that violate those natural laws meant to keep it stable. Manufacturing a deity from scratch has caused ripples in the timeline, affecting its linear in all directions and changing it forever. These ripples have altered history, retroactively inserting the deity into specific moments and events, forcibly making it part of the timeline and effectively retconning history. Now that the new reality has overlaid with the old one, this has created a paradox: the cult has essentially created the very god that they worship, which has led to inconsistencies within the space-time continuity. The god-child was born at a specific point in time, yet has always and will always exist within the past, present, and future.

However, there have been significant amounts of individuals throughout time who have become aware of these contradictions, both in the past and future. They have noticed the retcon and retain memories of the original timeline which no longer exist, as history has been rewritten to accommodate this new god. The world does not remember this past, and regard these people as crazy or liars. For them, their lives has always been this way. This is similiar to a software upgrade, such as going from a windows 95 to a windows vista. For those others, it is like they went to bed and woke up in an alternate world with a revised history. Since they were part of the same change as everyone else was, how could this have happened?

Comment: Wonderful writing. So if there's a material change throughout the timeline (past-present-future) but some folk have memories of the original, which their peers do not; I must ask do the memory-retaining people in the "future" have any records of memory-retaining people who lived before them? If only records of them being submitted to mental institutions. Because that is necessary to tell whether this event simply changed the timeline, or caused it to split into a myriad branches (one for each memory-retaining person).

Comment: @KeizerHarm No kidding wonderful writing. I'm pretty sure I've threatened Incognito that I'd hunt him/her down the throw handfuls of spaghetti at him/her if he/she didn't publish some of that writing. And the creativity! I recall being told that it was all being kept internal. Incognito is the only user on the Stack that I've entirely stopped VTCing for opinion-based questions because the stories are too darn good. I'm happy to award that dubious honor to anyone who can equal this fine, upstanding citizen's work quality.

Comment: @Join JBH on Codidact I actually took some of this backstory from the scarlet king. Scarlet King | SCPOneCanonProject Wiki | Fandom

Comment: So, You are saying that time in this case is like a line but that the introduction of an event gives this line some energy and begins to oscilate? And the points in the wave that pass through the pervious stationary points gives people memories of how things really were?

Answer (score 2):

**Fractal timeline**

If you have seen a Mandelbrot fractal, consider that matematicians suspect that it is all only one piece with one boundary. This boundary is a line of infinite length and with repeating shapes, every repetition slightly different. Time is actually like this, there are cycles, days, seasons.

Now, suppose the physical laws are to ensure reality closely adheres to this boundary. If they break down (or are broken by Leviathan) and reality skips to another timeline, there will be pieces of original timeline in the new place too - ***because of the self-repeating nature of the fractal!*** But they will be arranged a bit differently and perceived out of place. Same as if you zoom around the mandelbrot closely, there are infinitely many tiny copies of the main "bottle" all around the fractal.

Answer (score 0):

## Extra Dimensions of time:

I've tried to resolve this using the idea that time is like a [three-dimensional object](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176601/is-three-dimensional-time-consistent-and-paradox-free-for-time-dimension-travele). Every moment of time is happening somewhere/when, but it doesn't mean it is in the same linear plane as the reality you are experiencing. It's a variation on the "parallel universe" model, where they assume a parallel universe is a separate thing. Your out-of-phase people are simply experiencing the universe in a slightly different slice. Without distortion, all these slices would be identical (but offset fractionally in time).

The time object is distorted by the changes in time. For most people (following time like a sheet of paper or a string) warped time is something they bend with. But for others, their threads get tangled, broken, or warped . But both time lines still exist - the different past is still there, just out of phase with the new time reality. So the previous reality still exists in a fractionally different phase of reality; but in at least one of the dimensions of time, the new timeline predominates. It also resolves how such beings see paradoxical time themselves - they can see the extra dimensions of time.

Now, the new past always existed, but so did the old past.

Comment: I think that we understood the question differently. I thought the question was "Why do some people retain memories?" not "How could the the timeline-splitting have gone?" (although I did ask for clarification on that in the comment).

Comment: @KeizerHarm Having an underpinning that explains the "physics" of altering time is what I'm getting at. If different people are from unaltered parts of time, and are in this time state as a result of time breaking, it explains why they retain different memories.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could suggest that the people with memories are the only people that existed in the previous timeline - the ones with no memories were created by the changes.

Say for example person X became a worshipper of the newly inserted deity a couple of hundred years ago - they meet a different person who they marry and have different children, grandchildren, etc., meanwhile the person they would have married ends up having children with someone else, and then you add generations of knock on impacts from these changes (people end up in different jobs, with different friends, etc.)

In fact the problem might be if the changes go back far enough in history anyone being substantially the same person generations later in the alternate version could become problematic to justify - certain insular communities might last longer unchanged, but eventually given enough generations exacerbating whatever changes happened the impacts should be expected to reach everyone.

Compare with the known genetic impacts of people like Charlemagne - anyone alive long enough ago ends up the ancestor of virtually everyone many hundreds or thousands of years later (of course this is true of basically everyone that far back, it is just easier to trace famous people).

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeline (only one) or a 2D time-plane or a 3D time-space.

You introduce an event into the timeline/plane/space that gives some energy to the timeline/sheet/crystal.

That energy will propagate through the timeline/plane/space creating ripples on the previously static timeline/sheet/crystal.

That energy can be shown as a **vectorial energy**. In that case *you would need to acknowledge that the time has at least one more dimension*(timeline/sheet/crystal existing within a timeplane/space/hyperspace), to let that event create more than just one ripple.

[image: Top=VectorEnergyProp;Bottom=ScalarEnergyProp]

Or that energy could be propagated as a **scalar energy**. In that case you wouldn't need to acknowledge that there's one more time dimension. But *that would mean that the energy will just propagate on both directions of time only once*, never again touching the previous static/cold time.

This second type of event propagation wouldn't alow the apparition of people with memories of the previous untouched timeline while the first would.
But the first type would be a heavy hit on the phisics' knowledge of the universe while the second wouldn't.